# What is advantage of non absolutely abstract class over absolutley abstract class?

Tags: java, oop

An abstract class can have both abstract and non abstract method. Class have only abstract methods can called absolutely abstract class.

Comment: As you said: it can contain non-abstract methods, providing a common implementation shared by all subclasses of the abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

There is no advantage of one over the other.

- One approach allows you to share implementation code.
- The other approach allows you to *not* share implementation code.

You use whichever is *more appropriate* to the task that you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

If abstract class still has their childs and child has their own behaviors also some behaviors are common, in that case we sud go for  non absolutely abstract class